# Is srand() required in Julia?

Tags: random, julia

Some low-level languages like C require the programmer to set seed (usually `srand(time(0))` if the user wants a different sequence of random numbers whenever the program runs. If it is not set, the program generates the same sequence of random numbers for each run.

Some high-level languages automatically set the seed if it is not set at first.

In Julia, if I want to generate a new sequence of random numbers each time, should I call `srand()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you call Julia's `srand()` without providing a seed, Julia will use system entropy for seeding (essentially using a random seed).

On startup (specifically during initialisation of the [Random module](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/v0.6.2/base/random.jl#L182-L184)), Julia calls `srand()` without arguments. This means the global RNG is initialised randomly.

That means there's usually **no need to call `srand()` in your own code** unless you want to make the point that your random results are not meant to be reproducible.

Answer (score 4):

Julia seeds the random number generator automatically, you use `srand` with a known seed, in order to recreate the same pseudo random sequence deterministically (useful for testing for example), but if you want to generate a different random sequence each time, all you need is to call `rand`.

```rb
help?> srand
search: srand sprand sprandn isreadonly StepRange StepRangeLen ClusterManager AbstractRNG AbstractUnitRange CartesianRange

  srand([rng=GLOBAL_RNG], seed) -> rng
  srand([rng=GLOBAL_RNG]) -> rng

  Reseed the random number generator: rng will give a reproducible sequence
  of numbers if and only if a seed is provided. Some RNGs
  don't accept a seed, like RandomDevice. After the call to srand, rng is 
  equivalent to a newly created object initialized with the
  same seed.
```